# JavaScript events orders returning different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have 2 events attached to several select elements. A click event and a change event. When the user selects an option, I keep track of previously selected options on a JS object to tell the user that the option is already used and can't be reused and reset that select to the default value. If the select had a previous value that is not default, I remove the property from the object. Now, on each click event, I would have a JS variable give me the value of that select before the change happens. But, because of the difference in order of events been trigger (Firefox and Chrome) for example, in one I get the default which was when it reset, and the other I get the value right before the reset.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Objects test on Browsers</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <select name="dd1">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="bear">bear</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="dd2">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="bear">bear</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="dd3">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="bear">bear</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var alreadyUsed = {};
var prevField = "";

$(function() {
    // Events for drop downs
    $("select[name^='dd']").on("focus", function(event) {
        prevField = $(this).val();
        console.log(prevField);
    }).on("change", function(event) {
        var fieldInUsed = checkNotUsedAlready("fields", $(this).val());

        if (fieldInUsed === true) {
            delete alreadyUsed[prevField];

            $(this).val(0);
        } else {
            var selectField = $("select[name='" + event.target.name + "']" + " option:selected");

            if (selectField.html() != "-Select-") {
                alreadyUsed[selectField.html()] = $(this).val();
            } else {
                delete alreadyUsed[prevField];
            }
        }
    });
});

function checkNotUsedAlready(type, value) {
    var fieldColInUse = false;

    if (type == "fields") {
        for (var prop in alreadyUsed) {
            if (alreadyUsed.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if (prop == value) {
                    fieldColInUse = true;
                    alert("Field is already in use.\nPlease, select a different field.");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (type == "columns") {
        for (var prop in alreadyUsed) {
            if (alreadyUsed.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if (alreadyUsed[prop] == value) {
                    fieldColInUse = true;
                    alert("Column is already in use.\nPlease, select a different column or custom.");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return fieldColInUse;
}
```

1. I select cat on first drop down. Object now is Object{cat:"cat"}
2. I select dog on second drop down. Object is now Object {cat:"cat", dog:"dog"}
3. I select cat on second drop down.

At this point, firefox returns me dog as the previous value, which is what I want, but Chrome returns me zero because of the reset and when it set the value because of the events triggering order. Any ideas how can I deal with this in a different way?

One of the reasons for the JS object is that I need to have a list of which values are used to submit later and which are not used yet. A value needs to be unique.

**NOTE**: Choose cat for Drop down 1, dog for Drop down 2 and bear for Drop Down 3. Then, choose dog from Drop Down 1. On chrome, it will delete bear but on Firefox, it will delete cat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls provide js example or jsfiddle

Comment: based on the 3rd point in the example i have a question "Are you looping through the objects?" . also as @daremachine has said please provide a fiddle

Comment: while retrieving values are you using different names as dd1 and dd2 in both the cases in the form..???

Comment: provide your JS/jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would help to simplify things a bit. This works for me in Chrome, IE 9+, and Firefox:

```js
var alreadyUsed = [];

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("select[name^='dd']").data("previous","0");
    
    
    $("select[name^='dd']").on("change", function(event) {
        var newValue = $(this).val();
        var prevValue = $(this).data("previous");
        
        if(alreadyUsed.indexOf(newValue) == -1){
            if(prevValue != "0") alreadyUsed.splice( alreadyUsed.indexOf(prevValue), 1 );
            
            alreadyUsed.push(newValue);
            
            $(this).data("previous",newValue);
        }else{
            alert("Field is already in use.\nPlease, select a different field.");
            $(this).val(prevValue);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <select name="dd1">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="bear">bear</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="dd2">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="bear">bear</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="dd3">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="bear">bear</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

You code is a bit more complicated, and obviously does other things, but perhaps this simple working version will help.

Comment: Hey Seamus, had to use a object since I keep tracking of a name/value pair with another drop down per line but, using the idea of simplifying the code and the use of data attributes instead of what I had before, think I got it to work. Need to test it out on Linux Chrome and Firefox, but so far is working. Thank you for the ideas. Appreciate it.